# Is there a way to find the limit of a function algorithmically?

Tags: limits, algorithms

Is there a certain sequence of instructions that one may use to find the limit of a function?
I know that, $\lim_{x \rightarrow c}f(x)=L$ iff $f(x)$ gets arbitrarily close to $L$ as $x \rightarrow c$, but I don't see how I can use this definition to form an algorithm. Any advice?

Comment: If your algorithm can't look at (uncountably) infinitely many values of $f$ at once, then no.

Comment: But $f$ is a given function?

Comment: what does that even mean ? how do you describe a function to your algorithm ?

Comment: For example, if you wanted to find the limit of the function $f(x)=\frac{4^{x}}}{x-4}$ as $x \rightarrow 4$ - can this be done algorithmically?

Comment: @mercio You understand that an algorithm simply means "a sequence of steps"?

Comment: that's easy : step 1. write down "it diverges to infinity". step 2. stop. This is a good algorithm that answers correctly, right ?

Comment: And how did your algorithm deduce its result? You've got the last 2 steps, but none of the steps before that. Your algorithm is incomplete.

Comment: are you saying that "1. write down "it diverges to infinity". step 2. stop." is not an algorithm ? isn't it a sequence of steps ? it happens to give the right answer if you're thinking of $4^x/(x-4)$ too, which is amazing imo. Anyway, what kind of steps are allowed in your algorithms and how does your algorithms gets to ask things about $f$ ?

Comment: Well, suppose you wanted to write a program using JavaScript. You can't simply tell it to 'solve the problem', you have to give an explicit list of instructions explaining how to solve the problem.